# Returning a sublist which is not found in the DB

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to build a sql query which takes as input a list of ids and return those ids that aren't found in the DB. Is this possilbe?

Supposing I have this list of IDs: id1, id2, id3 and id4... If id3 and id4 are found in the DB it returns id1 and id2. Is this possible? Could someone show an example?

Comment: You mean it should return list1 and list2?

Comment: What SQL database are you using? What version?

Answer (score 2):

Make a virtually derived table, then LEFT JOIN that to the table and pick out where it does not exist in the table.

```
select madeuptable.find
from (
    select 'list1' find union all
    select 'list2' find union all
    select 'list3' find union all
    select 'list4' find
) madeuptable
left join tbl on tbl.somecolumn = madeuptable.find
where tbl.somecolumn is null
```

Comment: Yeah, I have undone votes before but I guess usually within the hour, but yeah, not worth it. It wasn't until I actually created a sample table/query that I realized I did A EXCEPT B instead of B EXCEPT A.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [except](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055.aspx) keyword in the select. The query is basically impossible to give to you because there is no information of the context and mainly, it is not clear weather list1 ... listn are actual lists or a lists's IDs.

Comment: The try with SELECT * FROM Lists WHERE ListID Not IN ('list1', 'list2', 'list3')

Comment: Pedro - as I erred too, he wants the ids in the _list_ that aren't in the _database_, not the ids in the database that aren't in the list.